# Custom JSON Encode a Struct

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a struct for converting an ASP.NET DateTime to unix time like so:

```
public struct UnixDateTime
{
    private readonly int _value;

    public UnixDateTime(int value)
    {
        this._value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator UnixDateTime(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        return new UnixDateTime((int)(dateTime - epoch).TotalSeconds);
    }

    public static implicit operator DateTime(UnixDateTime unixDateTime)
    {
        return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddSeconds(unixDateTime);
    }

    public static implicit operator int(UnixDateTime unixDateTime)
    {
        return unixDateTime._value;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(UnixDateTime unixDateTime)
    {
        return unixDateTime._value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Untested, please no one use that in their code without testing it.

Anyways, when I store this value in a ViewModel, send it to the view, then call:

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
```

It will output an empty object '{}' for that property.

What methods do I need to add to my struct in order for Json.Encode to properly output an integer value? Preferably, I would like it to NOT output an "object", but rather a "value"... so I don't want:

```
"Date": {"Value": 123456}
```

But rather:

```
"Date": 123456
```

**I know I can just add a getter onto the struct to get it to output like what I don't want, but I'd like this to work similar to how string or int types work.** Maybe this isn't possible without completely redoing Json.Encode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working, if you know a way to do this without JSON.net, then let me know:

1. Use Json.net
2. Create the following class:

   ```
   class UnixDateJsonConverter : JsonConverter
   {
       public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
       {
           return (objectType == typeof(UnixDateTime));
       }

       public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           // I'll figure this out later
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }

       public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           if (value == null)
           {
               serializer.Serialize(writer, null);
               return;
           }

           UnixDateTime dt = (UnixDateTime)value;
           serializer.Serialize(writer, (int) dt);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add `[JsonConverter(typeof(UnixDateJsonConverter))]` above the `UnixDateTime` struct.
4. Use `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject` instead of `Json.Encode` to turn it into json.

If anyone knows a better way to do this without json.net I will give you the answer. Json.net was already in my project so it worked out.